# Get all nodes within

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to get all nodes of the previous results with a certain tag.
The following code gets all nodes of the way, but I can't figure out how to only get the nodes with a certain tag.

```
[out:json][timeout:25];

(way["railway"="tram"](47.36889,8.55407,47.36973,8.55553));

out;
>;
//get all nodes within the result with a certain tag
out;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];

way["railway"="tram"](47.36889,8.55407,47.36973,8.55553);
>;
node._["public_transport"="stop_position"];
out;
```

It queries for all ways with a `railway=tram` tag in the given bounding box. Then it performs a recurse up (`>;`) to get all nodes of these ways . Afterwards it searches for nodes in the default set `_` with a `public_transport=stop_position` tag.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling a long time trying to achieve this.

Comment: You can also write: `way["railway"="tram"](47.36889,8.55407,47.36973,8.55553);
node(w)["public_transport"~"stop_position"];`